# RecyclerView gets not notified about visual changes when using the recyclerview-selection library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have implemented the recyclerview-selection library successfully. Now I am trying to make a "select all items" button with the method `SelectionTracker.setItemsSelected(keys: Iterable<K>, selected: boolean)`. So far so good. My problem is now that some of the items which are out of sight don´t get visually checked. But this just happens if I scrolled down to the list´s end bevor pressing the button. Under the hood all items get checked which I can see on the app bar´s text.

Example: I scroll to the end of the list and back up and press then the "select all items" button. As you can see in the picture there a some items that are visually not checked.

[image: 'n' and 'o' are not chekced]

Similar things happen if I press the back button to remove the checked state of all items.

---

Now my question: Is there a bug in the recyclerview libraries which causes this weird gui behaviour or am I doing something wrong? I am using the following version: `recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc03`

---

EDIT:

Here the bind method of my RecyclerView.ViewHolder class:

```
fun bind(event: Event, selected: Boolean) {
    val imgSize = if (selected) SELECTION_IMG_EXTENDED_SIZE else SELECTION_IMG_REDUCED_SIZE
    animateResize(imgSize, ...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onViewAttachedToWindow(VH)) I solved the problem by overriding the following method:

**RecyclerView.Adapter:**

```
override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
      val isSelected = selectionTracker.isSelected(holder.itemId)
      holder.setItemSelected(isSelected)
}
```

I don't know if this is the recommended way to solve the problem but maybe it will help someone. Let me know if you have any more tips or information for me!

---

EDIT:

Here the full code:

```
class EventAdapterAll(private val context: Context) : ListAdapter<Event, EventAdapterAll.EventViewHolder>(EventAdapterDiffCallback()) {

    private val commonListAdapter = CommonListAdapter()

    init {
        setHasStableIds(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): EventViewHolder {
        val binding = LayoutEventItemAllBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return EventViewHolder(binding)
    }

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: EventViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)
        commonListAdapter.selectionTracker?.let {
           holder.bind(currentItem, it.isSelected(getItemId(position)))
        }
    }

    override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: EventViewHolder) {
        val isSelected = commonListAdapter.selectionTracker?.isSelected(holder.itemId)
        if (isSelected != null) {
            holder.setItemSelected(isSelected)
        }
    }

    //...

    inner class EventViewHolder(private val binding: LayoutEventItemAllBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(event: Event, selected: Boolean) = with(binding) {
            setItemSelected(selected)
            //...
        }

        fun setItemSelected(selected: Boolean) {
            val imgSize = if (selected) SELECTION_IMG_EXTENDED_SIZE else SELECTION_IMG_REDUCED_SIZE
            commonListAdapter.animateResize(binding.imgEventSelection, imgSize, context)
        }
    }
}
```

When scrolling down/up and the list items become visible, `onViewAttachedToWindow` ensures that the selection status in the list gets updated.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach, you can do this in the `bind` as part of the adapter, basically like we do it here: https://github.com/ExpensiveBelly/RecyclerViewSelection/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/recyclerviewselection/ItemsAdapter.kt

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I added a part of my 'bind' method to the question. Of course I togle the view status according to the selection mode in the 'bind' method. To solve the problem described, I also have to override the 'onViewAttachedToWindow' method.

Comment: This essentially causes each view to be rebound when it becomes visible. May cause performance problems if the user is scrolling quickly. It does solve the problem though. @Tobi it isn't clear how your link solves the problem. It'd help if you could write an answer and explain what part addresses this.